# Catch exception for non numeric character

Tags: java, string, exception

I'm trying to convert a string to its number value, taking each character as it comes. The problem is that I want to throw an exception if the string has an alphabet or space (basically anything apart from a number). But it does not throw the exception and continues to convert basically any string to its number format. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I cannot use library functions for the conversion

```
for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= var; i--) {
                if (str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(0) <= '9') {
                    sum += (str.charAt(i) - '0') * Math.pow(10, power);
                    power++;
                } else {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
```

Comment: `(str.charAt(i) - '0')` you need to cast this value to an int and then multiply with Math.pow(). Right now, the ascii value for that resulting character is being multiplied

Comment: What is var in the for loop ? Is it 0 ?

Comment: @javaguy so the first character in the string can be a '-' or a '+'. SO I have another if condition before this to check if the first character is one of these two then var is set to 1 so that the for loop will only iterate till the second most significant place. If not, then var is 0 and the loop goes on till 0.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your if statement

```
if (str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(0) <= '9') {
```

should be

```
if (str.charAt(i) >= '0' && str.charAt(i) <= '9') {
```

Comment: Thanks! I corrected that. But now it returns a null for anything before the invalid character and then proceeds to return the rest of the string as a long. SO, "123hj34" was returned as: 
null
34

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so writing here.

Your probably don't want a str.charAt(0) <= '9'

Also think about handling '-' for negative numbers

Comment: I have accounted for negative numbers. SO I have another if condition before this to check if the first character is a '-' or a '+', then var is set to 1 so that the for loop will only iterate till the second most significant place. If not, then var is 0 and the loop goes on till 0.